# How Spring's Cacheable Annotation can work for class initailized through new Keyword. (In a Class Constructor, initialized through Bean)

Tags: java, spring, caching

In our service, we are initializing a bean (say "A") and that internally constructing a `CacheableService` Object by using - `new CacheableService()`. And as I know spring's `@Cacheable` annotations won't work on class method if the class is initialized using "new" Keyword.

Then what is an alternative or a way to cache method response?

**Scenario :**

```xml
<bean class="com.package.src.A"/>
```

```java
public class A {
    
    Map<String, CacheableService> map;
    public CacheableService2() {
        map = new HashedMap();
        map.put("a", new CacheableService());
    }
}
```

```java
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
    
public class CacheableService {
    
    
    @Cacheable(value = "entityCount", key = "#criteria.toString()")
    public int someEntityCount(final String criteria) {
        System.out.println("Inside function : " + criteria);
        return 5;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use full blown aspectj with compile time weaving, or build it yourself, or just use proper dependency injection.

Comment: Thanks Deinum. Can you please give any example of how can I do that using - aspectj with compile time weaving. And what do you mean by "build it yourself" ?

Comment: What M. Deinum said, use dependency injection. So in other words make your CacheableService a Spring managed bean and then autowire it into your class A. If you create your own class by calling "new" you place that instance outside of the Spring lifecycle so therefore Spring will not be able to manage that bean for you.

Comment: To use AspectJ compile time weaving you need to set up a different compiler, switch your AOP mode for the whole application to use AspectJ and not proxies. There are several tutorials as well answers here on stackoverflow on how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a minimum example which demonstrates caching using Spring Boot. The code for the examples below can be found [here](https://github.com/jonckvanderkogel/caching-demo).

Go to https://start.spring.io/ and create a new Spring Boot project. Make sure to include "Spring cache abstraction" which results in this entry being added to your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Add the @EnableCaching annotation to your application:

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;

@EnableCaching
@SpringBootApplication
public class CacheableApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CacheableApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Your service:

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class CacheableService {
    @Cacheable(value = "entityCount")
    public int someEntityCount(final String criteria) {
        System.out.print(String.format("Inside function: %s", criteria));
        return 5;
    }
}
```

Class A:

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class A {
    private CacheableService cacheableService;

    public A(@Autowired CacheableService cacheableService) {
        this.cacheableService = cacheableService;
    }

    public int getEntityCount(String criteria) {
        return cacheableService.someEntityCount(criteria);
    }
}
```

And then here is a test that demonstrates that the caching is working. As you can see in the test a.getEntityCount("foo") is being called twice, but in standard out we only see "Inside function: foo" being printed once. Therefore we have verified that the second call resulted in the cache being used to produce the result.

```
package com.example;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

@SpringBootTest
class CacheableTest {
    private final ByteArrayOutputStream outContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    @Autowired
    private A a;

    @BeforeEach
    public void init() {
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(outContent));
    }

    @Test
    public void testCaching() {
        a.getEntityCount("foo");
        a.getEntityCount("foo");

        assertEquals("Inside function: foo", outContent.toString());
    }
}
```

EDIT:
If you want to move the cache outside of the Spring lifecycle and manually manage it then I would recommend using [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine). Here is the same example but now without any Spring involved.

Your service:

```
package com.example.withoutspring;

import com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.Caffeine;
import com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.LoadingCache;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class CaffeineCachingService {
    private LoadingCache<String, Integer> entityCountCache = Caffeine.newBuilder()
            .expireAfterAccess(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .build(key -> someEntityCount(key));

    public int cachedEntityCount(final String criteria) {
        return entityCountCache.get(criteria);
    }

    private int someEntityCount(final String criteria) {
        System.out.print(String.format("Inside function: %s", criteria));
        return 5;
    }
}
```

Class B:

```
package com.example.withoutspring;

public class B {
    private CaffeineCachingService cacheableService;

    public B() {
        cacheableService = new CaffeineCachingService();
    }

    public int getEntityCount(String criteria) {
        return cacheableService.cachedEntityCount(criteria);
    }
}
```

And the same test but without Spring:

```
package com.example.withoutspring;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

public class CaffeineCacheableTest {
    private final ByteArrayOutputStream outContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    private B b = new B();

    @BeforeEach
    public void init() {
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(outContent));
    }

    @Test
    public void testCaching() {
        b.getEntityCount("foo");
        b.getEntityCount("foo");

        assertEquals("Inside function: foo", outContent.toString());
    }
}
```

Obviously you need to tune the cache to perform how you want it so probably evicting the cached values after 5 minutes is not what you want but if you visit the Caffeine Github page you will see a lot of detailed examples how to configure the cache to meet your use-case.

Hope this helps!